# How do I read the value from an input checkbox?

Tags: lightning, inputcheckboxes, checkbox

I am not managing to read out the value of a checkbox in my lightning component. Please find my code below:

**lightning component:**

```
< label class="slds-checkbox">
        < input type="checkbox" aura:id="news" class="slds-input" checked="{!v.identityRequest.Newsletter__c}" onchange="{!c.onChange}" />
< span class="slds-checkbox--faux"></span>< /label>
```

**apex controller:**

```
onChange : function(component, event, helper) {
    var identityRequest     = component.get('v.identityRequest');
    component.set('v.identityRequest',identityRequest);
    console.log(identityRequest)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you may just have the name of the event wrong.
On the checkboxes, the event being sent is called `change` like this:

```
component.cmp
<ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="checkbox" label="Select?" change="{!c.onCheck}"/>



controller.js
({
     onCheck: function(cmp, evt) {
         var checkCmp = cmp.find("checkbox");
         resultCmp = cmp.find("checkResult");
         resultCmp.set("v.value", ""+checkCmp.get("v.value"));

    }
})
```

Keep me posted if that solved your issue. I went by the documentation and have not tested it myself.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_ui_inputCheckbox.htm

Comment: Thanks, it was indeed the wrong name of the event. change was correct.

Answer (score 1):

change `<input type="checkbox"/>` to    `<ui:inputCheckbox />` and use the following code

```
        onChange : function(component, event, helper) {
            var identityRequest = component.find("news").get("v.value");
            component.set('v.identityRequest',identityRequest);
            console.log(identityRequest)
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the ui:inputCheckbox doesn't handle the onchange event listener. What could I use to replace this? Im pretty new to this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the below line of codes.

```
< input type="checkbox" id="news" value= "news" checked={!v.identityRequest.Newsletter__c}" onchange="{!c.onChange}" />

onChange: function(component, event, helper) {
    var check = document.getElementById("news").checked;
    alert('check ::'+check );
    //Rest of the codes...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can you use lightning: input with the checked attribute for dynamic binding

`<lightning:input type="checkbox" name= 'isMaster' checked="{!record.IsMaster}"></lightning:input>`

Comment: why is this downvoted so much? it's the correct answer.